# Docker image before development or after? (Beginner)

Tags: node.js, web, docker, socket.io, web-deployment

I am trying to build a website with Node.js and Socket.io with HTML5 canvas. I am new to docker and containers and am trying to understand how they work. I have a couple of questions that I would like help understanding.

1. Should docker be installed before development of the application or after?
2. Can I deploy docker on a Mac?
3. How to setup the environment to use the technology?

Questions may be naive but I am a beginner. I researched on google and most articles explain what docker is and how is it better than VM but not many show the usage or how-tos. Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you need to install Docker first.

From [there](https://docs.docker.com/) you can find detail official docker document on how to install docker on different Operating system.

2. You can [install docker on mac](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/). But docker doesn't run directly on Mac, it runs inside a linux virtual machine by using virtualbox
3. Following steps will help you learn Docker:

   - Learn how to [install docker on mac](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/) or you can install it on your preferred linux os.
   - [Docker Engine Quickstart](https://docs.docker.com/engine/quickstart/)

[Docker official document](https://docs.docker.com/) will be very helpful for you!

Happy Dockering!